# Error con EditText en Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, edittext

Estoy intentando algo muy simple en Xamarin Forms. Necesito tener un `EditText` y abajo un `Button` pero cuando intento crear el `EditText` me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código:

```
<StackLayout>

    <Label
        Text="!Prueba a pulsar el boton!"
        HorizontalOptions="Center"
        VerticalOptions="Center"/>

    <EditText/>

    <Button 
        HorizontalOptions="Center" 
        VerticalOptions="Center" 
        Text="Pulsame"/>

</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La etiqueta a utilizar correspondiente a EditText en android es Editor:

```
  <Editor Placeholder="Introduce el texto" />
```